# How to compare each x with the its latest index value when pop out the x

Tags: python, list

This is the list, I want to compare each x and its latest index value in a loop. While the x value is smaller than its index value, then pop out this x value in list. Otherwise X value remains.

```
i = 0
L = [7, 13, 4, 5, 10, 14, 3, 11, 7, 12, 5, 1, 8, 5, 3]
for x in L:
    if x <= i:
        list_pop = L.pop(i)
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
print(L)
```

Excepted output:
[7, 13, 4, 5, 10, 14, 11, 12]

While the x value is smaller than index value, this x will be pop out of list and the index value is changed.So I dont know how to compare the new index value with x. What can I do or change the total loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by latest value?

Comment: If you just want to remove the values whose index value is less than their actual value, you can just remove i+=1 from the if block, because when you remove the the value the index value is also shifted backward for the next elements and also iterate through the copy of the list (`L[:]`)

Comment: Because one x value is poped out of the list, so index value of later x value will advance one.( eg, the one which index value is 9 become 8)

Comment: **Never** modify a list while you're iterating over it (as you are doing) unless you're absolutely certain about the side-effect(s)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the copy of the list so that what ever changes made to the list won't affect your iteration and you shouldn't increment the index variable when you are removing the element. Because the index value of next items in the list will be decreased, when you are removing an element.
So something like this

```
i = 0
L = [7, 13, 4, 5, 10, 14, 3, 11, 7, 12, 5, 1, 8, 5, 3]
for x in L[:]:
    if x <= i:
        list_pop = L.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1
print(L)
```

Output:

```
[7, 13, 4, 5, 10, 14, 11, 12]
```

`L[:]` is slice operation, it "slices the entire list" and makes a new copy. This is essentially same as doing `L.copy()` and creates a shallow copy.
You can read more about them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html).

Without copying the L you can iterate through the list in reverse manner since the removal of an element doesn't matter for the index of previous elements.
A really non pythonic way would be

```
L = [7, 13, 4, 5, 10, 14, 3, 11, 7, 12, 5, 1, 8, 5, 3]
i = len(L)-1
while i>-1:
    if L[i] <= i:
        list_pop = L.pop(i)
    i -= 1
print(L)
```

More pythonic way to do this would be (Thanks to @MatBailie) for pointing it out

```
L = [7, 13, 4, 5, 10, 14, 3, 11, 7, 12, 5, 1, 8, 5, 3]
i = len(L)-1
for x in reversed(L):
    if x <= i:
        list_pop = L.pop(i)
    i -= 1
print(L)
```

reversed returns an iterator that give a mean to look through a list in reverse manner without creating a copy.

Comment: What's the difference between in L and in L[:] ? I'm little confused. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lorraine It creates a copy of the list L, every slicing operation creates a new list. In this case we are slicing the entire list making a copy of entire list. So we are iterating through the clone of list while modifying the original list `L`, so that removal of elements won't affect our iteration.

Comment: For remotely large lists, copying the list is "expensive". Alternatives *(such as iterating over the generator `reversed()`)* avoid that expense.

Comment: @MatBailie It is true that copying is not free and that it can be avoided, but the list would have to be really big or your resources really low before it would become "expensive".

Comment: @zvone Expense is relative, which is why in this case I put it in quotes; to indicate that it's only Expensive when compared to the alternative of not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [7, 13, 4, 5, 10, 14, 3, 11, 7, 12, 5, 1, 8, 5, 3]
i = len(L) - 1

for x in reversed(L):
    if x <= i:
        L.pop(i)
    i -= 1

print(L)
```

This way, using `pop()` doesn't change which element comes next in the iteration.

`reversed()` is also a generator, and so avoids the expense of answers based on making copies.

***EDIT:***

An alternative would be to create a new list, avoiding the need to repeatedly call `pop()`, which is likely the most expensive part of this process.

```
L = [7, 13, 4, 5, 10, 14, 3, 11, 7, 12, 5, 1, 8, 5, 3]

L_filtered = [
  val for ix, val in enumerate(L)
    if val > ix
]

print(L_filtered)
```

Demo, including timings: https://trinket.io/python3/e85cc235c3